# Attach an event on a future element

Tags: javascript

I need to call a function just after some elements are loaded on the page(result of a ajax call) after the page loads, I cannot use the success callback function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Your question is very different form the title of the question.

Comment: Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect moment when elements are added into DOM, then execute code in listener callback.

Answer (score 0):

From your title seems that you need to attach a callback (example on click callback).
You can use **event delegation** directly with javascript:
Example:

```
// Get the element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("ajax-target").addEventListener("click", 

    function(e) {
        // e.target is the clicked element!
        // If it was a list item
        //Future elements
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
            // List item found!  Output the ID!
            console.log("List item ", e.target.id.replace("post-"), " was clicked!");
        }
    });
```

With jQuery this would be really easy:

```
$('#ajax-target').on('click', '.future-elements', function(e){
   console.log('some future elements was clicked');
});
```